# scenekit SCNShadable u_diffuseColor reads as white

Tags: swift, glsl, scenekit

I'm trying to set a breakpoint via:

```
gl_FragColor = u_diffuseColor;
return;
```

or

```
gl_FragColor = _surface.diffuse
return;
```

in `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface` but i always get white, regardless of what i've set in the scn editor.

Let's say i set the `diffuse` as red in the editor:

```
//hub.geometry?.materials = [material]; //diffuse is red
hub.geometry?.materials = [material]; //diffuse is white
```

Why is this uniform not being affected by the gui, or being overwritten, or whatever is going on? I'd like to be able to set the 'diffuse' through the gui, get a preview in the editor, and read it in GLSL from either `u_diffuseColor` or `_surface.diffuse`